# Were three journalists (Bob Simon, Ned Colt and David Carr) investigating a plausible relation between the CIA and 9/11?

Tags: media, 9-11, cia

Apparently these three journalists all died within a couple days of each other (Feb. 11 to 12, 2015). The implication of some rumours going around is that these folks were killed because they have evidence showing that the CIA had some involvement in 9/11.

There are [several web-sites discussing this](http://lainfo.es/en/2015/02/19/authors-died-documentary-about-us-action-in-11-s/), with excerpts such as:

> The [three plus Brian Williams] presented documents required for access to confidential documents file Kremlin (Russian Government headquarters) containing evidence linked to the attacks occurred on September 11, 2001.
>
> The work of the four journalists sought to discover the truth of the attack on the twin towers. David Carr was who devised to make the film after seeing the audiovisual documentary Citizenfour and study each confession exanalista CIA Edward Snowden.

Were these three collaborating on an investigation into the CIA in relation to 9/11? If so, is there any reason to believe they had any persuasive evidence?

[image: Bob, Ned and David]

Comment: I'd like to have an easy and clear counter to this, like there usually is, but the three died to a stroke, a car accident, and a collapse that was liked to pneumonia and lung cancer (which could be said to have masked however he "really" died because it would have killed him soon regardless).  I still find it highly implausible, but I can't actually write an answer to counter it.

Comment: @Bobson The question is not about how they died: it's about whether they were investigating "the CIA in relation to 9/11", e.g. whether they had "presented documents required for access to confidential documents file Kremlin".

Comment: @ChrisW But we also have "The implication of some rumours going around is that these folks were killed because they have evidence.. ". While the question you refer to IS the title, would this even be a story if we remove the potential CIA link? I'm sure there's 3 more journalists working on the story now, or even 30 or more.

Comment: @ChrisW - My point was simply that the methods of their deaths don't disprove the "killed for their investigation" claim like I was expecting it to.

Comment: While not dispositive, David Carr was a culture reporter. This would be way off his beat.

Comment: I am not able to parse "...presented documents required for access to confidential documents file Kremlin", at least i think so: My parsing of this part leaves me with something weird like "...showed passports which are required for accessing a file, called 'Kremlin' full of confidential documents". - Can someone give confirmation or a different reading?